# Typescript - function syntactically 'between' arguments

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

Some functional programming languages provide the ability to call your functions inline 'between' arguments. I do not know the correct terminology for this functionality (if I did, I could do a better search :D), but hopefully the following is clear..

Let's say I define an 'add' function:

```
const add = (a,b) => a+b;
```

For reasons that are outside the scope of this question (**I'm not here for a debate on coding style, there is a legitimate use-case here, I promise**), I would like to be able to call this function like so:

```
const result = 1 add 3;
```

For my obviously more complicated situation than the above, this syntactic sugar would be very tasty. Is it possible in typescript? And what is the correct terminology/name for the behaviour above allowed in some languages?

Comment: No, you'd have to write your own parser, probably one that transpiles to JS

Comment: Not possible... the closest I can think of in actual TypeScript to simulate infix functions would look like `_(1)(add)(3)` as in [this code](https://tsplay.dev/nWPqzw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology for this is an 'infix function', and no, it's largely not possible in TS.

Typescript is a very thin layer over Javascript: with only a few exceptions, it only supports the syntax that Javascript supports as well as the type annotations.

[And Javascript doesn't have infix functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350790/is-it-possible-to-define-an-infix-function), so Typescript doesn't either.

---

The only way it's remotely possible is with a [TS transformer](https://github.com/madou/typescript-transformer-handbook), which is essentially writing a custom transpiler plugin that transpiles code *to* normal Typescript syntax.

But those are fragile and not very well supported, so I wouldn't recommend it for a syntax sugar use-case like this, personally.